# Entity Framework 6 Disable Interception temporarily

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, soft-delete

I am using an `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` to enable soft deletes on my model.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(
     new SoftDeleteInterception());
```

I want to be able to disable the interceptor temporarily so that I can select a "deleted" entity for auditing purposes.

However, It seems like the `DbInterception` collection is assembly-wide.

Is there any way to create a new `DbContext` *without* interception on?
Or even a way to add the interceptor to the `DbContext` every time it is created?

Comment: Hi, Have you figured out how to do that?

Comment: @jekcom Unfortunately, no.  I ended up having to do some (insane) reflection on my context to get what I wanted out of it.  If you find a way, please let me know.

Comment: I actually solved it (kind of). Will post the answer here, may be it will help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have extended my db context class with additional property

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(DbConfig))] 
public partial class YourEntitiesDB 
{
    public bool IgnoreSoftDelete { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the TreeCreated(...) method i check this flag and if true then it just doesn't go further to the QueryVisitor

```
public class SoftDeleteInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public SoftDeleteInterceptor()
    {

    }
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        var db = interceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault() as YourEntitiesDB;
        if (db!=null && db.IgnoreSoftDelete)
        {
            // Ignore soft delete interseptor (Used in archives)
            return;
        }

        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.CSpace)
        {
            var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
            if (queryCommand != null)
            {
                var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new SoftDeleteQueryVisitor());
                interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                    queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                    queryCommand.DataSpace,
                    newQuery);
            }

            var deleteCommand = interceptionContext.OriginalResult as DbDeleteCommandTree;
            if (deleteCommand != null)
            {
                var column = SoftDeleteAttribute.GetSoftDeleteColumnName(deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.EdmType);
                if (column != null)
                {
                    var setClauses = new List<DbModificationClause>();
                    var table = (EntityType)deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.EdmType;
                    if (table.Properties.Any(p => p.Name == column))
                    {
                        setClauses.Add(DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(
                                DbExpressionBuilder.Property(
                                    DbExpressionBuilder.Variable(deleteCommand.Target.VariableType, deleteCommand.Target.VariableName),
                                    column),
                                DbExpression.FromBoolean(true)));
                    }

                    var update = new DbUpdateCommandTree(
                        deleteCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        deleteCommand.DataSpace,
                        deleteCommand.Target,
                        deleteCommand.Predicate,
                        setClauses.AsReadOnly(),
                        null);

                    interceptionContext.Result = update;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to use it i just set  the flag to true when needed

```
YuorEntitiesDB DB = new YuorEntitiesDB();
DB.IgnoreSoftDelete = true;
DB.Records.Where(...)
```

Comment: Man, I swear I tried this and it didn't work, but it looks like it solved the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Updating answer, for this to work you need to also include AsNoTracking()

Comment: @BlackTigerX could you explain why exactly you need to use AsNoTracking() ? I pesronaly don't use it and it works fine

Comment: I can't get this to work either - only the first time it seems to run as expected. It seems the TreeCreated method is only run on the very first query pr. entity type (and then cached?). So setting IgnoreSoftDelete to true will work on first query, but changing the property back to false won't work subsequently. This behavior is true whether recreating the Entities instance or not. 
Please elaborte @jekcom if you can get this to work...in which case I must be missing something.

Comment: @MichaelH.Pedersen TreeCreated is visited only after you enumerate the query. E.g. if you do DB.Records.ToList() you will see it is being visited. I can't assist you much without seeing the code. So if you wish, you could open a new question with a code that does not work and we will try to help

Comment: @MichaelH.Pedersen this is why you need to use .AsNoTracking

Comment: @jekcom for the problem that Michael is having

Comment: @jekcom Thanks. I still can't make TreeCreated run more than once regardless of how I enumerate and use .AsNoTracking() (thanks @BlackTigerX). I ended up writing my own .SoftDelete() extension instead. It's not quite as elegant...but that I can get working.

Comment: @BlackTigerX i'm sorry, but your edit to my answer is misleading. It works without AsNoTracking() and I facilitate all the features of EF6 including saving changes. So unless you can explain exactly why .AsNoTracking() makes a difference, please do not make such edits and do not write any edits as if it was me. If you think your answer is better feel free to post it as new answer

Comment: @MichaelH.Pedersen can you show how you add the interceptor to your db context?

Comment: @jekcom should I specify that if it doesn't work for you, adding .AsNoTracking fixes it? it is definitely the case for me and Michael

Comment: @MichaelH.Pedersen look at the edits, and see if adding .AsNoTracking fixes the problem for you

Comment: @BlackTigerX I have tried every possible combo of settings, enumerations and whatnot. Still can't make it work. For the time being I'm sticking with my own implementation so I can get on the project at hand. jekcom I'll whip up a small example of what I've done and post somewhere in a few days.

Comment: @jekcom here's an example of my implementation. It's not a thing of beauty, but for now it get's the job done. It's on jsfiddle...didn't know where else to put it. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/svhm9w1u/)

Comment: @MichaelH.Pedersen, Ah, I see now. We are probably talking about 2 different things. The issue discussed here is related to **Interceptors** in general. And particularly using technique similar to the one that is described in [this topic](http://marisks.net/2016/02/27/entity-framework-soft-delete-and-automatic-created-modified-dates/)

Comment: @jekcom Maybe I didn't phrase my response correctly. But I meant to say, that I just ditched the soft delete interceptor altogether and came up with a different type of solution....not a fix to making the actual interceptor work. But you probably figured this be now. My apologies.

Comment: yeah, I guess I'll add it as another answer, to avoid the conflicts on this one, my apologies, I was just trying to make it more complete